# Trying to plot cross validation

Tags: tikz-pgf

I’ve come up with this wonderful plot. I need you to help me draw it:

[image]

> MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (M) [matrix of nodes,
        nodes={minimum height = 7mm, minimum width = 2cm, outer sep=0, anchor=center, draw},
        column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none}, minimum width = 4cm},
        row sep=1mm, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, nodes in empty cells,
        e/.style={fill=yellow!10}
      ]
      {
        Experiment 1 & |[e]| & & & & \\
        Experiment 2 & & |[e]| & & & \\
        Experiment 3 & & & |[e]| & & \\
        Experiment 4 & & & & |[e]| & \\
        Experiment 5 & & & & & |[e]| \\
      };
      \draw (M-1-2.north west) ++(0,2mm) coordinate (LT) edge[|<->|, >= latex] node[above]{Total number of datasets} (LT-|M-1-6.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Guidance on how to draw it as it appears on the screen shot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A drawing like this can be made in many different ways. For this particular drawing I would suggest using a `\foreach` loop rather than `\matrix` environment, as it provides more flexibility for making the contours of the bars and individual blocks.

The example below can furthermore easily be scaled by changing the `scale=0.7` of the whole picture and the `scale=0.5` of the right-hand side of the picture in the `scope` environment. The secondary purpose of the `scope` environment is to define a node of its bounding box to draw the arrow that connects both halfs of the pictures together.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0mm,minimum height=1cm,outer sep=3mm,scale=0.7,>=Latex,font=\footnotesize,
  indication/.style={minimum height=0cm,outer sep=0mm},
  oneblock/.style={transform shape,minimum width=1cm,draw},
  fullset/.style={transform shape,minimum width=10cm,draw}]
    % left part of picture
    \node[fullset,anchor=west] at (0,0) (A) {};
    \node[above=of A.north,indication] (ATXT) {TRAINING SET};
    \node[oneblock,minimum width=2cm,anchor=west,right=of A,fill=lightgray,outer sep=0mm] (A1) {};
    \path (ATXT) -| (A1) node[midway] {TEST SET};
    \node[fullset,anchor=west] at (0,-4) (B) {};
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9}
    {
        \draw (B.west) +(\x,0) node[oneblock,anchor=west,draw] {};
    }
    \draw[->] (A) -- (B) node[midway,fill=white,indication] {divide into 10 folds of equal size};

    % right part of picture
    \begin{scope}[xshift=15cm,scale=0.5,local bounding box=rightside box]
    \foreach \x in {0,1}
    {
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,4}
        {
            \draw (\x*11,0) +(0,-\y*2) node[fullset,anchor=west] {};
            \draw (\x*11,0) +(\x*5+\y,-\y*2) node[oneblock,draw,anchor=west,fill=lightgray] {};
        }
    }
    \coordinate (R) at (rightside box.west);
    \end{scope}

    % connecting arrow
    \draw[->] (B.east) -- +(2.5,0) node[below,align=center,indication] {run experiments\\using 10 different\\partitionings} |- (R);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: It looks awesome! I’ll try to add some shadows to it!