# Subsample from k-Fold cross-validation figure using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to have a figure of having a subsample from k-fold cross-validation. I have gone through the post regarding cross-validation and I have found 2 post that can help me construct the cross-validation in [k-Fold cross-validation figure using TikZ or table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429451/k-fold-cross-validation-figure-using-tikz-or-table) and [Trying to plot cross validation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500368/trying-to-plot-cross-validation).

I hope to have the figure of sub sample as below:

[image: subsample from fold]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0mm,minimum height=1cm,outer sep=3mm,scale=0.7,>=Latex,font=\footnotesize,
 indication/.style={minimum height=0cm,outer sep=0mm},
  oneblock/.style={transform shape,minimum width=1cm,draw},
  fullset/.style={transform shape,minimum width=10cm,draw}]
% left part of picture
\node[fullset,anchor=west] at (0,0) (A) {};
\node[above=of A.north,indication] (ATXT) {TRAINING SET};
\node[oneblock,minimum width=2cm,anchor=west,right=of A,fill=lightgray,outer sep=0mm] (A1) {};
\path (ATXT) -| (A1) node[midway] {TEST SET};
\node[fullset,anchor=west] at (0,-4) (B) {};
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,9}
{
    \draw (B.west) +(\x,0) node[oneblock,anchor=west,draw] {};
}
\draw[->] (A) -- (B) node[midway,fill=white,indication] {divide into 10 folds of equal size};

% right part of picture
\begin{scope}[xshift=15cm,scale=0.5,local bounding box=rightside box]
\foreach \x in {0,1}
{
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,4}
    {
        \draw (\x*11,0) +(0,-\y*2) node[fullset,anchor=west] {};
        \draw (\x*11,0) +(\x*5+\y,-\y*2) node[oneblock,draw,anchor=west,fill=lightgray] {};
    }
}
%node
\draw[color=red!60,very thick](1,0) circle (1.2);
%line
\draw[black, thick] (0.7,0) -- (0.7,3);
 \draw[black, thick] (0.7,0) -- (3,3);
  \draw[blue, very thick] (0.8,3.1) rectangle (3,5);
 \draw[blue, very thick] (3.2,3.2) rectangle (5,5);
\coordinate (R) at (rightside box.west);
\end{scope}

% connecting arrow
\draw[->] (B.east) -- +(2.5,0) node[below,align=center,indication] {run experiments\\using 10 different\\partitionings} |- (R);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is what i obtained
[image]

how can i get a more elegent figure?

Comment: Please make your code compilable in the form of a MWE (I have retracted my close vote and -1)

Answer (score 2):

I defined a new style `block` in the final `scope`, used `\node`s to draw the rectangles with labels, and used the node names to draw the connecting lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0mm,minimum height=1cm,outer sep=3mm,scale=0.7,>=Latex,font=\footnotesize,
 indication/.style={minimum height=0cm,outer sep=0mm},
  oneblock/.style={transform shape,minimum width=1cm,draw},
  fullset/.style={transform shape,minimum width=10cm,draw}]
% left part of picture
\node[fullset,anchor=west] at (0,0) (A) {};
\node[above=of A.north,indication] (ATXT) {TRAINING SET};
\node[oneblock,minimum width=2cm,anchor=west,right=of A,fill=lightgray,outer sep=0mm] (A1) {};
\path (ATXT) -| (A1) node[midway] {TEST SET};
\node[fullset,anchor=west] at (0,-4) (B) {};
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,9}
{
    \draw (B.west) +(\x,0) node[oneblock,anchor=west,draw] {};
}
\draw[->] (A) -- (B) node[midway,fill=white,indication] {divide into 10 folds of equal size};

% right part of picture
\begin{scope}[
  xshift=15cm,
  scale=0.5,
  local bounding box=rightside box,
  block/.style={minimum height=0mm,outer sep=0, draw, inner sep=2mm} % <--- new
]
\foreach \x in {0,1}
{
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,4}
    {
        \draw (\x*11,0) +(0,-\y*2) node[fullset,anchor=west] {};
        \draw (\x*11,0) +(\x*5+\y,-\y*2) node[oneblock,draw,anchor=west,fill=lightgray] {};
    }
}
%the next six lines are new
\coordinate (pointofinterest) at (1,0);
\draw[color=red!60,very thick] (pointofinterest) circle (1.2);

\node [above right=5mm and 5mm of pointofinterest, name=70, block] {70\%};
\node [right=1cm of 70, name=30, block] {30\%};

\draw (pointofinterest) -- (70);
\draw (pointofinterest) -- (30);


\coordinate (R) at (rightside box.west);
\end{scope}

% connecting arrow
\draw[->] (B.east) -- +(2.5,0) node[below,align=center,indication] {run experiments\\using 10 different\\partitionings} |- (R);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you @Torbjørn T. as expected.